# Error inflating class huawei.android.widget.ImageView android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

In my Android app, I customize a Notification view that shows some buttons in XML file as below. It worked for most of devices, but showing this error on Huawei Nova i7:

*Couldn't inflate `contentViewsandroid.view.InflateException:` Binary XML file line #13 in my_app_package:layout/notification_idle: Binary XML file line #13 in my_app_package:layout/notification_idle: Error inflating class `huawei.android.widget.ImageView`
`android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage`*

I wonder why it is `huawei.android.widget.ImageView` in the error message. It should be: `android.widget.ImageView` as my understanding.
If you have an answer, that would be appreciated.

Here is my XML file for the notification view

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/gap_small"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_notification_logo"/>`
```

Comment: Seem it's confusing at ImageView, I think about the fix at  `<android.widget.ImageView` instead of `<ImageView`?

Comment: Is it worked for you? just explicit set android.widget.ImageView?